# How to access the function in main.rs which has been written in a file in different directory in rust in same package

Tags: module, rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I want to call a function inside a main.rs file. I have made one directory name "library" inside the same src folder as main.rs exist.

src/main.rs

```
mod library;

fn main() {
   println!("{}", library::name1::name(4));
}
```

src/library/file.rs

```
pub mod name1 {
    pub fn name(a: i32) -> i32 {
        println!("from diff file {}", a);
        a * a
    }
}
```

when I call this function name in main.rs, compiler throws an error:

> error[E0583]: file not found for module library

I think I am missing something. What is the correct way to do this? Keep in mind that the library directory is just an ordinary directory not a cargo package

Comment: No its not from another file it is to call the function from another directory in the same src directory

Comment: Hi there! Your problem is not about calling the function. The error message you posted is about your `mod library;` statement. The Rust compiler should show that line below the error message. In short, the solution to your problem is: rename`library/file.rs` to `library/mod.rs`. You should also remove `pub mod name1` as one usually does not use inline `mod` definitions. I hope this helps. But I recommend you to read through the answers in the linked questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this issue in 2 different ways:

1 ) Using Module
2 ) Using Library

**Using Module**

Simply create a file next to main.rs in **src** directory and name it **name1.rs**

name1.rs will look like:

```
//no need to specify "pub mod name1;" explicitly
pub fn name(a: i32) -> i32 {
   println!("from diff file {}", a);
   a * a
}
```

main.rs will look like:

```
//name of the second file will be treated as module here
pub mod name1;

fn main() {
   println!("{}", name1::name(4));
}
```

**Using Library**

a) create a library, standing in main project directory (i.e. parent of src directory) and run the command below:

```
//In your case library name "file"     
$ cargo new --lib file
```

This command will create another directory of name file same as your main project.

b) Add this library(file) in the dependency section of Cargo.toml file of main project

```
[package]
name = "test_project"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["mohammadrajabraza <mohammadrajabraza@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"


# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
file = {path ="file"}
```

c) A file under main_project>file(library)>src>lib.rs will be created, once you created library using command above.

lib.rs will be look like:

```
pub fn name(a: i32) -> i32 {
             println!("from diff file {}", a);
             a * a
}
```

d) and finally your main.rs will be:

```
//importing library in thescope
use file;

fn main() {
   println!("{}", file::name(4));
}
```

Comment: also delete the "library" directory you created in the src directory

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in src directory named as library.rs and than in library.rs write the following code:

```
pub mod file;
```

Than access the same function from your main file as you are doing right now.Than it will work properly.

You can follow this method too

https://github.com/Abdul-sid/PIAIC-IOT-RUST-CLASS/tree/master/13th-Oct-chapter-7-part-2/dir-mod-bin/src

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of library which rust have in it.
Simply making a library project having the --lib flag.

```
cargo build library --lib
```

After doing it. You will write this in your dependency section in *Cargo.toml*.

```
library = {path = "./src/library"}
```

You can even use the absolute path of your directory.

```
library = {path = "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/Rust/jawwad/src/library"}
```

Then write your library code in lib.rs file.

```
pub mod name1 {
    pub fn name(a: i32) -> i32 {
          println!("from diff file {}", a);
          a * a
    }
}
```

Here is the main.rs file.

```
use library;

fn main() {
   println!("{}", library::name1::name(4));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue. The error is the same as I change the file name to library.rs